# How to shorten a mvn console call correctly?

Tags: maven

How would I go about shortening a maven console call like the following?

`mvn clean process-resources frontend:install-node-and-npm frontend:npm frontend:grunt package tomee:run`

into something like:

`mvn myCommand`

---

I am looking for a way to define it inside the `pom.xml`.
I am looking for a solution that doesn't profit from shifty hacking like binding each command to a lifecycle phase between `process-resources` and `package` as there could be more commands in-between those two easily.

Comment: Did you try it with [Maven Profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) ?

Comment: Problem with invoking the same plugin multiple times in an order that needs to be maintained

Comment: Why not using the life cycle? What is exactly the problem with the life cycle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want should work through using plugins and execution phase. This [should](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/maven-plugin-execution-order-in-same-phase/) help you.